# Facebook v2.4 API Finding a users top friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make an app that shows the user their top 10 friends on facebook.
I've researched a lot of solutions on stackoverflow but they were all posted a few years ago and now do not work with the new restrictions imposed by the v2+ Api. 
How would you propose ordering the users friends list to show the most likely top friends. (Friends of the user do not have the app installed)

Answer (score 0):

You can only access friends who authorized your App too. More information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)